# Is there any theme record count?

Tags: paging, database

Is there any theme record count? Like: "Showing 1 to 10 of 186 records".

So that the user sees the number of pages and total number of records of a query (EntityFieldQuery).

Something made my drupal like theme pager, that we use like this:

```
//...
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
//...
$query->pager(10);
//...
$content .= theme('pager');
//...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can easily make one yourself by implementing [`hook_theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7).

Comment: so it's not possible to integrate with the pager? it would make it easier to get the current page/number of pages